# Change the taskbar settings programmatically?

Tags: windows, settings, taskbar

I want to change the settings of my taskbar with a small batch file or java programm or whatever.
So I want to know, if there is a registry key containg this information.

Does anybody knows, where Windows sets taskbar settings?

Edit: No, I don't want to annoy the users with changing taskbar settings on every boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
```

and 64 bit eqivalent?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have any clue how I can solve my problem with this piece of information. Could you please provide some more information?

Comment: Sorry, you asked where the settings for task bar are saved. For example animations are controlled in 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\TaskBarAnimations

Comment: I use the Small taskbar on my laptop screen and the Large taskbar on my monitor.  I've added a shortcut to the following batch file on my taskbar to toggle between the two with one click.

Comment: @echo off  
  
SET KEY=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced  
SET VALUE=TaskbarSmallIcons  
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3" %%X IN (`reg query "%KEY%" /v "%VALUE%" 2^>nul ^| find "%VALUE%"`) do (
    if /I "%%X" EQU "0x0" SET TOGGLE=1
    if /I "%%X" EQU "0x1" SET TOGGLE=0
)

REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /V TaskbarSmallIcons /T REG_DWORD /D %TOGGLE% /F

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
start explorer.exe

Answer (score 0):

[TaskBarCmd](http://mihai-nita.net/2007/09/09/taskbarcmd-programmatically-change-the-windows-taskbar-settings/) seems to do the job.  It includes C++ source code.  It uses the [IBandSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647027.aspx%20iBandSite%20COM%20Interface) COM Interface.  Haven't tried the source, but the compiled version seems to work.